# Implicit conversion between 3rd party types

Tags: c++, type-conversion

There are two classes: `A` and `B`. There are algorithms for converting from type `A` to type `B` and back. We cannot touch the source code of them. Can I write an implicit conversion between the two types?

Example code which should work:

```
B CalculateSomething(double x)
{
    A a(x);
    a.DoSomethingComplicated();
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Implicit conversion often cause more harm than good, since you do not know what will happen just when looking at code. A simple wrong assignment can result in strange behavior. You should be really carefull when using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Implicit conversion is usually coded with an overloaded operator. It is done for base types too. As you can't modify A and B code there is no way to tell the compiler how to do that. Your snippet will get an error.

You have to do explicit conversion. Just

```
return helper.convertToB(a);
```

my2c

Comment: "Implicit conversion is usually coded with an overloaded operator." Or using an implicit constructor. I'd prefer the latter, although I have learned the hard way to shy away from any implicit conversions.

Comment: @sbi : I agree. I ALWAYS prefer EXPLICIT conversion. Ah, readability and ease of maintenance, why are you so much underestimated ...

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can write a named free function to do it.

```
B ToB( const A & a ) {
   B b;
   // process a somehow to add its data  to b
   return b;
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
B CalculateSomething(double x)
{
    A a(x);
    a.DoSomethingComplicated();
    return ToB( a );
}
```

which is arguably clearer than the implicit conversion would be.

Answer (score 0):

> There are two classes: A and B. There are algorithms for converting from type A to type B  and back. We cannot touch the source code of them. Can I write an implicit conversion between the two types?

No, if `A` and `B` aren't related you can't. (And I am grateful for that. Implicit conversions give enough headaches as they are without the ability to create them for 3rd-party classes.)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without altering class definition

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't change the implementation of A or B, you could add an inline constructor to the definition of B that takes a const A&.

I would suspect however that unless the classes really are closely related it would be better to provide an explicit conversion function - implicit conversions can be a huge source of difficult-to-find bugs:

```
B CalculateSomething(double x)
{
    A a(x);
    a.DoSomethingComplicated();
    return ConvertAToB( a );
}
```

Comment: How would you do that without touching the source code of A & B?

Comment: You are not talking about modifying 3rd-party headers, do you? Otherwise you are going to get some nice shiny binary incompatibility.

Comment: You shouldn't get any binary incompatibility if you do not change the vtable of the class (i.e. don't add any virtual methods). This isn't a nice solution, it is the only solution if (for whatever reason) you really need the implicit conversion.

As I said in the second part of my answer, implicit conversions are generally bad - my recommendation (as others have stated) would be an explicit conversion method or helper.